# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error happens in an UITableViewController with subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, subclass, exc-bad-access

I have an UITableViewController to manage an table view which created with subclassed prototype cells. The most related codes is as following:

**MyCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ScrollViewTableCellInShorTrip : UITableViewCell
@end
```

**MyCell.m**

```
#import "MyCell.h"
@implementation SMyCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{   
NSLog(@"touch cell");
[super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
}
@end
```

**TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arr;
@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "MyCell.h"
@implementation ATripTableViewController
@synthesize arr;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
MyCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

return myCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailView"sender:self];     
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailView"]){
   NSLog(@"arr acount is %d", self.arr.count);//program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
}   
}
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS error message is appear when calls "NSLog(@"arr acount is %d", self.arr.count)" in the prepareForSegue:sender: method. It is obviously that the property "arr" is free now. And The situation appears only when i use the subclassed UITableViewCell.

Appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLog(@"arr acount is %d", self.arr.count);` replace to `NSLog(@"arr acount is %d",arr.count);`

**definition of self:**
 self is a special variable which is a pointer to the object which received the message which invoked the currently executing method(!). In other words, it is the receiver of the message.

when you should call  `self.object` rather than calling the object directly within an object.

```
self.object = obj;
object = obj;
```

The difference between these two calls is that a call to self.object will make use of the accessors generated by the @synthesize directive. A call to the object directly will bypass these accessor methods and directly modify the instance variable

Answer (score 2):

count is a primitive (integer), not an object, as you are referring to it as with %@. use %i instead.

Comment: a better way would be **[self.arr count]**

Comment: I would say that's a matter of preference as self.arr.count and [self.arr count] is semantically the same thing. Property getters can be accessed both ways.

Comment: sorry, it's a typo, i just use %d. The problem is the property arr is freed, in the "NSLog(@"arr acount is %@", self.arr.count);"